# Optimizing Python SQL result loop

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have the following working code:

```py
async def loadnames(self, ctx):
    """
    Load the current alias of every member in the database.
    Useful after joining a new guild or after a long downtime.
    """
    async with ctx.message.channel.typing():
        message = await ctx.send(f'Adding members to the database... {ctx.author.mention}')
        db = await aiomysql.connect(host=globals.mysql_host,user=globals.mysql_user,password=globals.mysql_passwd,db=globals.mysql_db)
        cur = await db.cursor()

        #await cur.execute("SELECT discord,name FROM aliases WHERE discord=%s AND name=%s", (member.id,str(member)))
        #result = await cur.fetchall()

        count = 0

        for member in ctx.guild.members: 
            try:           
                result = await cur.execute("SELECT * FROM aliases WHERE discord=%s AND name=%s", (member.id,str(member)))
                if result == 0:
                    count = count + 1
                    await cur.execute("INSERT INTO aliases (discord,name) VALUES(%s,%s)", (member.id,str(member)))
                    await db.commit()
            except:
                await ctx.send(f'Error adding `{member}`! {ctx.author.mention}')
        await cur.close()
        db.close()
        await message.edit(content=f'{count} members added to the database! {ctx.author.mention}')
```

Now, this works perfectly fine, the only issue I see with this is that I'm executing a new SELECT query for every iteration of my loop. So I'd like to put the SELECT statement outside of the loop, using `cur.fetchall()` to put it in a list (see commented lines in the code above), but I don't know after that how to check if a pair of `(member.id,str(member))` is in my results.

Comment: 1. fix your "fetch all" sql to - SELECT discord,name FROM aliases WHERE discord in (.... all member ids ..) 2. on this result, loop to find which members ids are not present, collect them as List 3. insert from this list to DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derived from Parfait's answer, I ended up with this:

```py
async def loadnames(self, ctx):
    """
    Load the current alias of every member in the database.
    Useful after joining a new guild or after a long downtime.
    """
    async with ctx.message.channel.typing():
        count = 0
        message = await ctx.send(f'Adding members to the database... {ctx.author.mention}')

        db = await aiomysql.connect(host=globals.mysql_host,user=globals.mysql_user,password=globals.mysql_passwd,db=globals.mysql_db)
        cur = await db.cursor()
        await cur.execute("SELECT discord, name FROM aliases")
        result = await cur.fetchall()

        new_member_list = [(member.id, str(member)) for member in ctx.guild.members]
        member_list = [(member[0],member[1]) for member in result]
        diff_list = [member for member in new_member_list if member not in member_list]

        count = await cur.executemany("INSERT INTO aliases (discord, name) VALUES (%s, %s)", diff_list)
        await db.commit()
        await cur.close()
        db.close()

        if count is None: count = 0
        await message.edit(content=f'{count} members added to the database! {ctx.author.mention}')
```

Only one SELECT query at the beginning, then we play with the different lists to get the `executemany` `INSERT` statement which will do only the required number of insertions.

Comment: not sure how many records you have, but `cur.fetchall()` is a red flag. you dont need to fetch that from server with @prafait's solution

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot With say 1000 members in the database and only 10 new to add, the way I'm doing it is 1 select and 10 inserts. With prafait's 1st solution it's 1000 selects and 10 inserts. With his second solution... 1 delete, 1000 inserts then 1 last insert (with join selects). So in terms of the pure number of queries for my typical load, mine is more optimized. Python-wise... `cur.fetchall()` is probably just as bad as using the temp table with the 1000 inserts but heh. I'd have to do benchmarks to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a single insert-select query in loop using the well know duplicate avoidance in SQL: [**`NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`**](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/). Below runs the `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` approach:

```
for member in ctx.guild.members: 
    try: 
        sql = """INSERT INTO aliases (discord, name) 
                 SELECT a1.discord, a1.name
                 FROM aliases a1
                 LEFT JOIN aliases a2
                    ON a1.discord = a2.discord
                    AND a1.name = a2.name
                    AND a1.discord=%s AND a2.name=%s
                 WHERE a2.name IS NULL AND a2.discord IS NULL
             """
        result = await cur.execute(sql, (member.id, str(member)))
        count = cur.rowcount
        await db.commit()

    except:
        await ctx.send(f'Error adding `{member}`! {ctx.author.mention}')
```

---

Even better, populate member IDs in a temp table and join to above query for only ***one*** query for all member IDs. SQL's set-based processing beats out application layer looping!

```
# CLEAN AND POPULATE TEMP TABLE
await cur.execute("DELETE FROM mytempTable")
members_list = [(member.id, str(member)) for member in ctx.guild.members]
await cur.executemany("INSERT INTO mytempTable (discord, name) VALUES (%s, %s)", 
                      members_list)
await db.commit()

# ONLY ONE INSERT QUERY
sql = """INSERT INTO aliases (discord, name) 
         SELECT a1.discord, a1.name
         FROM aliases a1
         INNER JOIN mytempTable t
            ON a1.discord = t.discord
            AND a1.name = t.name
         LEFT JOIN aliases a2
            ON a1.discord = a2.discord
            AND a1.name = a2.name
         WHERE a2.name IS NULL AND a2.discord IS NULL
     """
result = await cur.execute(sql, (member.id, str(member)))
count = cur.rowcount
await db.commit()
```

Comment: Ha, this is brilliant and definitely more effective than what I currently have, although having only one SELECT at the beginning and then looping for the INSERTs would end up being less queries than this.

Comment: I am not understanding your comment. Here, there is only one `cur.execute` call inside the for-loop, not two `cur.execute` as you have it. The dupe check for each pair of *discord* and *name* is done in SQL not Python.

Comment: Let's assume there are 100 members and 50 of them are already in the database. So the for loop iterates 100 times. In my example, I'm doing 100 SELECT queries and 50 INSERT queries. In your first example, it's 100 queries no matter the number of members already in the database, so this is obviously an improvement (100 < 150). However, why do 100 queries if I only need 51 (1 SELECT query and 50 INSERT queries)? Or better yet, 1 SELECT and 1 INSERT? In your second example we do 1 DELETE, 100 INSERT in myTempTable, and then one last query at the end.

Comment: With all of that said, I don't know if from a performance standpoint it matters at all. It probably doesn't unless you are some sort of big corporation.

Comment: Understood re number of queries. Consider checking performance on your end. By the way, consider `executemany` (as edited) to pass a list of tuples in one call for `INSERT INTO myTempTable` approach. IMO: I would avoid `for` loops with back and forth calls between database and application layer as much as possible for set-based, [ACID](https://www.essentialsql.com/what-is-meant-by-acid/) operations to handle transactions at once and not iterative.

Comment: All right. So I tried the second solution as it looks more elegant but it doesn't add any member. The members do get added to the aliases_temp but not to aliases even after I truncated the table. Also had to change the last cur.execute statement to remove the member reference.

Comment: I was able to simplify it with what I think is the minimum number of queries. One SELECT and the `executemany` for the INSERTS. Let me know what you think.